# Drupal 7 Wildcard menu like txt-txt-% is not locating

Tags: routes

I wanted to create wildcard menu like text-text-% in drupal 7.

But It works for if the menu is like text-text/% how can I make the above menu format to locate the action.

```
 $items['pin-code-%'] = array(    
        'title' => 'Country list',
        'description' => 'Country pincode',
        'page callback' => 'country_pincode',
        'access callback' => true,
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard menu items for root level is not supported. 
Partial match wildcards are not supported either.

You can, however, remap incoming requests to a proper menu router that Drupal supports by implementing [`hook_url_inbound_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_inbound_alter/7). Unless there is a strict requirement to use the path pattern you mention, I wouldn't go for this solution because this hook is executed to every request, including normal pages and Ajax requests.